# How gradle jettyrun to exclude some class files?

Tags: java, gradle, jetty

I use gradle to build my java web project, in my source code package I have some source files I don't want to run in jettyrun.

How could I do? Thanks.

```
src
  |--main
    |--java
      |--xxx.xxx.donotWantToRun
      |--xxx.xxx.other
```

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: "war"
apply plugin: "jetty"

jettyRun {
  // I will exclude xxx.xxx.donotWantToRun package
  // How to do?
}
```

Comment: Here is DSL for `jettyRun`: http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.plugins.jetty.JettyRun.html. It seems that You just need to remove the the files from `classpath`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem, just excluded the package form sourceSets is ok.

```
SourceSets {
  main {
    java {
      exclude "**/donotWantToRun/**"
    }
  }
}
```